# sqlite3: select top n records in a column

Tags: python, sqlite

I've searched online and found how to return top N records

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 LIMIT 10;
```

but I want to find top N records that have highest values in a certain column...
What would be the syntax for it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the `ORDER BY` clause in the sqlite documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 order by field desc limit 10;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Check sqlite's doc is awesome, also this book is enlightening: http://www.amazon.com/Using-SQLite-Jay-A-Kreibich/dp/0596521189